# Debug Jackson with Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson

I just wrote some code in multiple files in my Spring REST API and I have Jackson errors now.

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start 

embedded container; nested exception is 

org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:168) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        ... 11 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConverters org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.messageConverters; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private final java.util.List org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.converters; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'c'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'c'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'c'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'c'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConverters org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.messageConverters; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private final java.util.List org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.converters; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'c'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'c'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'c'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'c'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        ... 34 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private final java.util.List org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.converters; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'c'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'c'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'c'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'c'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        ... 36 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private final java.util.List org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.converters; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'c'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'c'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'c'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'c'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        ... 56 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'c'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'c'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'c'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'c'
              at
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        ... 58 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'c'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'c'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:464) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
       at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        ... 71 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'c'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f58f482c.jacksonObjectMapperBuilder(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        ... 99 common frames omitted
```

I can't find what the error is and none of my files are specified in the error. Is there a way to get a better Jackson error output? I know you can't really help without the code but there are too many classes to put everything here.

I have this dependency for jackson in my pom.xml, I'm unsure which version it is.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: How have you injected it into the application context? Or are you using spring boot?

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot, it worked well before my recent changes so I don't think it comes from how I inject Jackson in my application but rather from my code. I have edited some DTOs some REST endpoints and some models. I'm looking for a way to get a better error output.

Comment: Do you ahve a custom MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter method in the @Configurtion file? In there if you have a custom ObjectMapper can you add that code too.

Comment: The only config I have for Jackson is this `spring.jackson.date-format=ch.heigvd.formVersion.configuration.RFC3339DateFormat
 spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS=false`

Comment: Can you change it to something like spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd and see if it starts.

Comment: It does work with `yyyy-MM-dd`. I don't understand, it used to work well.

Comment: It's a little late to answer, but I think the `spring.jackson.date-format` in `application.properties` is referring to a different location than where your `RFC3339DateFormat.java` actually is?

Answer (score 12):

I found this using Swagger, with spring mvc as the server type, I found the error to be in application.properties as generated by swagger...

```
springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path=/api-docs
server.contextPath=
server.port=8080
spring.jackson.date-format=io.swagger.RFC3339DateFormat
spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS=false
```

In my case the 'i' in the error

aused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder]: Factory method 'jacksonObjectMapperBuilder' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'i'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate

Was a result of the io.swagger.RFC3339DateFormat

I am currently experiencing this problem, and at least removing that line gives me a new and different error...at least it's a breadcrumb.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue. In my case, it turned out that the date format class was being generated in a different directory. I had to update the the default entry in application.properties to

```
spring.jackson.date-format=com.company.date.RFC3339DateFormat
```

Comment: Thanks, Same issue. Changing the package to point to correct one resolved this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code is failing in the following method of Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.

```
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder simpleDateFormat(String format) {
        this.dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        return this;
    }
```

Can you put a debugger in this method and post the format which is being passed here?

Answer (score 0):

This can be because of the property not pointing to the generated RFC3339DateFormat class.

Snippet for reference. As mentioned below the RFC3339DateFormat class is in com.test.config,

```
package com.test.config;

import java.text.FieldPosition;
import java.util.Date;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ISO8601DateFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ISO8601Utils;


public class RFC3339DateFormat extends ISO8601DateFormat {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 @Override
 public StringBuffer format(Date date, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition fieldPosition) {
   String value = ISO8601Utils.format(date, true);
   toAppendTo.append(value);
   return toAppendTo;
  }

}
```

The below entry in the property file should point to RFC3339DateFormat under com.test.config,

```
spring.jackson.date-format: com.test.config.RFC3339DateFormat
```

Answer (score -1):

Somewhere in the code, you misspelled with the character 'c'. That's where I see  your error log.